# File upload with AWS and javascript

Tags: javascript, file, select, amazon-web-services

Is there a file select library, similar to drop zone, that just manages the file selection process and lets me control how the files are uploaded?  It seems to me, unless I have missed something - most of these libraries require you to identify a server side file that will handle the upload.  Currently, my set up is such that files are sent to my server and then to S3 - which is far less efficient than sending them directly to AWS via the javascript API.

I like how dropzone lets me select files from multiple directories - adding to the list of files to upload on the fly.

Comment: It looks like people have posted solutions online to use Dropzone with S3. Have you looked at those?

Comment: I am currently using dropzone with S3.  The issue is, moving the file to S3 occurs after the file is uploaded to my server.  I want to bypass this, and upload directly to S3 from the web page with javascript - also, something i am doing, but not integrated with drop zone.

Comment: Yes I understood your question, and I saw that people have succeeded in getting dropzone uploading directly to S3. Have you looked at those solutions?

Comment: nothing seems to be specificly solved - One solution is for dropzone from aptonic, which I believe is defferent than the dropzone.js  I am using.  One method is using pyhton - others a different framework.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/33 The last message looks like it has a solution to uploading directly to S3 using Dropzone